# Hide cells in GridView based on another column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2012

I have the following GridView:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="SysInvoiceID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceID" HeaderText="SysInvoiceID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SysInvoiceID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BillMonth" HeaderText="BillMonth" SortExpression="BillMonth" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceDate" HeaderText="InvoiceDate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="InvoiceDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceNumber" HeaderText="InvoiceNumber" SortExpression="InvoiceNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Net" HeaderText="Net" SortExpression="Net" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VAT" HeaderText="VAT" SortExpression="VAT" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Gross" HeaderText="Gross" SortExpression="Gross" />
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="ViewInvoice"  HeaderText=" " ShowHeader="True" Text="View" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

The very last column (ButtonField) is one I created myself just to include the text 'View' on each row, which when clicked, will bring up a PDF invoice.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I was wondering if it was possible to add some sort of validation for that column or something, so that if the 'InvoiceID' column is blank, the 'View' link on the corresponding row won't show up.

I felt close to doing this by going on split view in Visual Studio and then the 'Edit Columns' button on GridView tasks, but like I said I'm not sure if it's possible to do it this way and may have to resort to simply coding it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `<TemplateField>` instead of a `<ButtonField>`

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button runat="server" Text="View" 
         Visible='<%# Eval("IsEmpty(InvoiceID)") %>' CommandName="ViewInvoice" />
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

And add a method to your page that is `IsEmpty(string id)` or whatever type your id is, and just check to see if it's empty first.

You can also add a `CommandArgument` attribute to the Button that will let you specify what the argument to it will be.

Comment: I need to make use of CommandName="ViewInvoice" or the rest of my code won't work.

Comment: Saved my day and from opening a new question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a placeholder...

```
<asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="plView" Visible="<%# Convert.ToBoolean(InvoiceID == null) ? false : true %>">
    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="ViewInvoice"  HeaderText=" " ShowHeader="True" Text="View" />
</asp:Placeholder>
```